# Nightwatch with Jquery integration fails with the error jQuery requires a window with a document

Tags: jquery, nightwatch.js

i am using nightwatch for end to end testing, i am facing one issue while using jQuery with night-watch.

While running this test case i am getting error like:

> jQuery requires a window with a document

Could you please let me know the reason .ad also i have included the JQquery library like this:

```
var $ = require('jquery').
browser.perform(function(dir)){
var flag = `$`('span').hasClass('red'); //throws error 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just going from your code snibbit, and what seems to be relavent:

I don't think you need the back ticks.  If you load in jquery correctly you should be able to just use the $ or jquery variables normally:

```
var flag = $('span').hasClass('red');
```

If you are unsure that you are loading jQuery correctly, check out requireJS's awesome documentation [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html)

The documentation does use a config file, and you don't have it listed, so I'm otherwise assuming you have this set up correctly.

Otherwise, I'm looking through my learn-nightwatch project (test simple Nightwatch setup), and I don't see any of the tests needing to specifically include jquery.  I would check with this, because I have never seen the "quickstart" Nightwatch tests to include jquery, and I'm able to use jquery fine (It defines it in the html).

The other possibility is that Nightwatch is attempting to test the page before it has actually loaded, Although there would be more information needed about your setup to see if this is possible.